# Script Issue (Incrementation)

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm writing a script in bash. My output down below is wrong. The test data I'm pulling from makes it so that all connections allowed and denied should be in time "00" yet for every day I crawl through it bumps to the next hour. I have my code below and sample output at the very bottom. Can you help me? It's giving me a headache.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "MEGA CRAWLER BY DA INTERNS" > Result

echo "Enter the month of the file you're trying to read"
echo "If month is one number enter one number if two numbers enter two numbers"
read M

#case staement changes M input into a month an reassigns single digit months into double digit
if [[ $M -lt 13 && $M -gt 0 ]]
then
case "$M" in
"1") month="Jan" ; M="01" ; Dlim="31"
;;
"2") month="Feb" ; M="02" ; Dlim="29"
;;
"3") month="Mar" ; M="03" ; Dlim="31"
;;
"4") month="Apr" ; M="04" ; Dlim="30"
;;
"5") month="May" ; M="05" ; Dlim="31"
;;
"6") month="Jun" ; M="06" ; Dlim="30"
;;
"7") month="Jul" ; M="07" ; Dlim="31"
;;
"8") month="Aug" ; M="08" ; Dlim="31"
;;
"9") month="Sep" ; M="09" ; Dlim="30"
;;
"10") month="Oct" ; Dlim="31"
;;
"11") month="Nov" ; Dlim="30"
;;
"12") month="Dec" ; Dlim="31"
;;
esac
else
echo "Please make sure to enter a valid month."
read M
fi

echo -e ""

echo "Enter the year of the file you're trying to read"
read Y

echo -e ""

for D in $(seq -f "%02g" 1 5); do
File=($(find -name "traffic_$M-$D-$Y"))
echo "-------------------------DAY $D-------------------------" >> Result
  for i in $(seq -f "%02g" 0 23); do
    grep "$month $i" $File > TempOutput
    countAllow=($(grep -c "allow" TempOutput))
    countDeny=($(grep -c "deny" TempOutput))
    echo -e "$countAllow            connections     allowed     at  $i time" >> Result
    echo -e "$countDeny             connections     denied  at  $i        time\n" >> Result
rm TempOutput
done
done
```

---

```
-------------------------DAY 01-------------------------

0           connections     allowed     at  00 time
0           connections     denied  at  00 time

77          connections     allowed     at  01 time
25          connections     denied  at  01 time

0           connections     allowed     at  02 time
0           connections     denied  at  02 time

-------------------------DAY 02-------------------------

0           connections     allowed     at  00 time
0           connections     denied  at  00 time

0           connections     allowed     at  01 time
0           connections     denied  at  01 time

76          connections     allowed     at  02 time
26          connections     denied  at  02 time
```

Comment: In the `grep "$month $i" $File` line, just to check, you are looking for line(s) that have the month followed by the hour, right? (It just seems a little strange to me.)

Comment: Wow I didn't even notice that, it was so simple! Thank you!